# How to make an Angular Service Worker recognize new versions of a deployed application in a static-hosted S3 bucket hosted in AWS CloudFront

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, angular-service-worker

When statically hosting an Angular Single-Page Application website in an S3 bucket through CloudFront, the errors have to be set to redirect to the index.html as HTTP 200 responses in order for the PathLocationStrategy to work as intended.  The Angular service worker depends on the ngsw.json receiving a 404 response in order to recognize that there is a new version of the application available, so a proper setup with CloudFront effectively breaks the ability to cache-bust the application on the client-side.

Is there a method one can use to trigger the client-side application to know there is a new version available to reacquire this cache-busting service?

Answer (score 0):

I did not try that, but here is my guess. You can configure S3 bucket as 'Static website hosting', set `index.html` as the 'Error document' and change origin to point to the S3 static website, then remove 'Error Pages' from the CloudFront distribution. Then you can configure webpage redirect/error specifically for `ngsw.json` in S3 static hosting settings.

Comment: This is a new take on things; Can you elaborate on what you mean by remove "Error Pages" from the CloudFront distribution?

Comment: I mean custom error page configuration for distribution

Comment: So you're saying you can achieve the PathLocationStrategy error page setting from S3 rather than CloudFront, and then configure it specifically for ngsw.json so it still returns 404?

Comment: Yes, exactly, however I did not try that.

Comment: Seems plausible; I'll have to try it out.

Comment: If you remove the error pages, you don't land back on the website for any error returned; you end up off the page -- I'm not sure custom redirects work as expected for this behavior and I'm not sure how you would accomplish that for a whole bunch of individual requests -- I don't think that is really doable in a practical way.  I think I'll have to try to trigger the change manually.